# Retrive all stored values in local storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

**Primary requirement**

What I really wants to achieve is that there is a text box with a button where user can input values and then those values will be saved into `localStorage` via different `key`s (so that even in page refresh these values can be retrieved) and also inserted values will be displayed under the text box.

What I did to accomplish this:

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <input type="text" name="userInputs" placeholder="Please insert the value" id="idUserInputs">
  <button onclick="insertUserInput()">Add</button>
  <p id="hiddenP"></p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
  var i = 0;
  function insertUserInput() {
    i++;
    //fetch the value
    var insertedValue = document.getElementById("idUserInputs").value;
    //set the value to show user
    document.getElementById("hiddenP").innerHTML = insertedValue;
    //set the value to localstorage with different key(via incremental i)
    window.localStorage.setItem("savedValues" + i, insertedValue);
  }
</script>
```

To retrieve the data if user refresh the tab just added `<body onload=funcrtion()` and the function coded as shown below:

```
<body onload="onloadRetrieveData()">

 function onloadRetrieveData() {
      //check the length 
      var length = localStorage.length;
      var x;
      for (x = 1; x <= length; x++) {
        document.getElementById("hiddenP").innerHTML = window.localStorage.getItem('savedValues' + x);
      }
```

This will retrieve the last data that user inserted. Like below

[image: snap]

I started this based on this article

[The complete guide to using localStorage in JavaScript apps](https://blog.logrocket.com/the-complete-guide-to-using-localstorage-in-javascript-apps-ba44edb53a36/)

What I wants right now is when user refresh the tab all saved data in local storage to be retrieve and show to user. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way one way to accomplish this, using the code you already have with a few small adjustments for how you add the final result to the DOM:

```
var hiddenP = document.getElementById('hiddenP');
var ul = document.createElement('ul');

function onloadRetriveData() {
  //check the length 
  var length = localStorage.length;
  var storedValues = [];
  console.log(length);
  var x;
  for (x = 1; x <= length; x++) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var textContent = document.createTextNode(window.localStorage.getItem('savedValues' + x));
    li.appendChild(textContent);
    ul.appendChild(li);
  } 
  hiddenP.appendChild(ul);
}
```

That would show all of the items in local storage in an unordered list, you could of course choose to display them in any format you wish.

Here is a short summary of what's going on, in case anything is unclear.

**Code Summary**

In this version, we are creating an unordered list:

```
var ul = document.createElement('ul');
```

Then, we add each item from local storage to the list as we go through the loop:

```
for (x = 1; x <= length; x++) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var textContent = document.createTextNode(window.localStorage.getItem('savedValues' + x));
    li.appendChild(textContent);
    ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

Notice that we create a new list element each pass:

```
var li = document.createElement('li');
```

Then, we create a textNode with the item from local storage as the value:

```
var textContent = document.createTextNode(window.localStorage.getItem('savedValues' + x));
```

Then, we add this text node to the list item and finally add the list item to the unordered list using the appendChild() method:

```
li.appendChild(textContent);
ul.appendChild(li);
```

Then, after the loop, we add the whole list to the hiddenP paragraph element, again using the appendChild() method:

```
hiddenP.appendChild(ul);
```

Comment: @DanielSchroeder can you check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57547302/how-to-keep-users-input-printed/57547911#comment101559289_57547911 . I think you are the best person to answer this. Thanks

Comment: @NipunTharuksha thanks for the heads up, gave it my best shot here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57562010/5347875

Comment: @DanielSchroeder Great job